# PostgreSQL multiple 'WHERE' conditions (1000+) request

Tags: java, database, postgresql, performance, spring-mvc

I'm not a pro in SQL at all :) 
Having a very critical performance issue.
Here is the info directly related to problem.

I have 2 tables in my DB- table `condos` and table `goods`.

table `condos` have the fields:

- id (PK)
- name
- city
- country

table items:

- id (PK)
- name
- multiple fields not related to issue
- condo_id (FK)

I have 1000+ entities in `condos` table and 1000+ in `items` table.

The problem is **how i perform items search**

currently it is:

For example, i want to get all the items for `city = Sydney`

1. Perform a `SELECT condos.condo_id FROM public.condos WHERE city = 'Sydney'`
2. Make a `SELECT * FROM public.items WHERE item.condo_id = ?` for each `condo_id` i get in step 1.

The issue is that once i get 1000+ entities in `condos` table, the request is performed 1000+ times for each `condo_id` belongs to 'Sydney'. And the execution of this request takes more then a 2 minutes which is a critical performance issue.

So, **the questions is:**

What is the best way for me to perform such search ? should i put a 1000+ id's in single `WHERE` request? or?

For add info, i use **PostgreSQL 9.4** and **Spring MVC**.

Comment: Area you aware of table joins?  From your question it seems you are not, and if not you need to learn about them.  This is exactly the type of problem a join is intended to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you need is to eliminate the N+1 query and at the same time ensure that your City field is indexed. You have 3 mechanisms to go. One is already stated in one of the other answers you have received this is the SUBSELECT approach. Beyond this approach you have another two.

You can use what you have stated  :

```
SELECT condos.condo_id FROM public.condos WHERE city = 'Sydney'

SELECT * 
FROM   public.items 
WHERE  items.condo_id IN (up to 1000 ids here)
```

the reason why I am stating up to 1000 is because some SQL providers have limitations.

**You also can do join as a way to eliminate the N+1 selects**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   public.items join  public.condos on items.condo_id=condos.condo_id  and condos.city='Sydney'
```

Now what is the difference in between the 3 queries.

**Pros of Subselect query** is that you get everything at once.
The Cons is that if you have too many elements the performance may suffer:

**Pros of simple In clause**. Effectivly solves the N+1 problem,
Cons may lead to some extra queries compared to the Subselect

**Joined query pros**, you can initialize in one go both Condo and Item.
Cons leads to some data duplication on Condo side

If we have a look into a framework like Hibernate, we can find there that in most of the cases as a fetch strategy is used either Joined either IN strategies. Subselect is used rarely.

Also if you have critical performance you may consider reading everything In Memory and serving it from there. Judging from the content of these two tables it should be fairly easy to just upload it into a Map.

Effectively everything that solves your N+1 query problem is a solution in your case if we are talking of just 2 times 1000 queries. All three options are solutions.

Comment: thanks thats the most full answer. one more small question - if i have multiple `WHERE` parameters also, should i specify them in `AND` operator?

like: `and condos.city='Sydney' and item.name='item1' and item.price=1999` and so on (if i use JOIN query)

Comment: Theoretically you can put them either straight in the join clause or after the where clause. I know that for the different DB providers there might be some small difference in performance , but you have to test this yourself. So yes either you specify them with AND conditions in the where clause or you place them straight in the JOIN clause again with AND.

Comment: i guess there is a mistake `public.items join  public.condos on item.condo_id=condos.condo_id`  Need `items.condo_id=condos.condo_id`. But in common seems like work. thanks!

Comment: Yes there is a typo. I will fix it.

Comment: No sory I dont see it. I dont have experience with PostgreSQL so the Postgre syntax is not well known to me. Where is the error ?

Comment: Table name is `items`, so need `items.condo_id` instead of `item.condo_id`. No?

Comment: i used `items.condo_id`

Answer (score 2):

Use a table `join` to perform a query such that you do not need to perform a additional query. In your case you can join `condos` and `items` by `condo_id` which is something like:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM public.items i join public.condos c on i.condo_id = c.condo_id 
WHERE c.city = 'Sydney'
```

Note that performance tuning is a board topic. It can varied from environment to environment, depends on how you structure the data in table and how you organize the data in your code.

Here is some other suggestion that may also help:

Try to add index to the field where you use sorting and searching, e.g. `city` in `condos` and `condo_id` in `items`. There is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work) to explain how indexing work.

I also recommend you to perform `EXPLAIN` to devises a query plan for your query whether there is full table search that may cause performance issue.

Hope this can help.

Comment: This is not much related to the question, except the join part.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen OP said he has a critical performance issue and execution of a request takes more then a 2 minutes. So I provide suggestion about how to better resolve it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first query as a subquery in an `in` operator in the second query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   public.items 
WHERE  item.condo_id IN (SELECT condos.condo_id 
                         FROM   public.condos
                         WHERE  city = 'Sydney')
```